# is it right choose to connect database in template page directly in Wordpress site?

Tags: database, automatic-updates

i'm a little bit new in WordPress and for now working on WordPress site that some information will insert to database from forms ... i design some page template and use mysqli_connect() to connect database and mysqli_query() to insert data to database .

the question i wonder is , am i do mistake ? is it possible that pages or piece of database erase after WordPress updates or totaly Could something bad happen? should change anything or not ?

i will thanks to anyone that help me. :)

Comment: If you do it right, nothing will break. But wordpress has a lot of build-in functions to CRUD posts, meta, terms, users and so on. For very complex solutions there is wpdb class for working with wp database. Why you desided to use mysqli_connect() instead?

Comment: because for that time i not familiar with  wpdb class ...

Comment: then i sure about my template pages that nenver will delete because of updates and etc ?

Answer (score 0):

If you make data manipulations with `mysqli_connect()` right, according to database structure etc, it will not break your site. But it's more safe and logical to use build-in functions to manipulate database data. (Some standarts exists). Wordpress has a lot of functions, which allows you to manipulate each wp table's data. Here are some simple functions as an example:

**Posts, pages, CPT** 
Insert or update post - [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)
Update post - [wp_update_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)
Trash or delete post - [wp_delete_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/)
**Post meta**
Add post meta - [add_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)
Update post meta - [update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)
Delete post meta - [delete_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_post_meta/)
**Taxonomy terms**
Insert term - [wp_insert_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/)
Update term - [wp_update_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/)
Delete term - [wp_delete_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_term/)
**Terms meta**
Add term meta - [add_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)
Update term meta - [update_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)
Delete term meta - [delete_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_term_meta/)
**Options**
Add option - [add_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/)
Update option - [update_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)
Delete option - [delete_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_option/)

If you working with custom database tables, check [wpdb class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/), which allows you to manipulate with database safely, and you don't need to worry about connections etc. Each link from wordpress codex, where are a lot of simple examples you can use, the same sql queries if you use wpdb.